# Listen to jQuery event without jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-events

Is there a way to set up an event listener, so it captures an event fired by jQuery? I want to use only plain (vanilla) JavaScript to listen to the event.

I have set up the following example:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).on('sent_jquery_rec_jquery', function () {
        console.log('sent_jquery_rec_jquery');
    });

    $(document).on('sent_vanilla_rec_jquery', function () {
        console.log('sent_vanilla_rec_jquery');
    });

    document.addEventListener('sent_vanilla_rec_vanilla', function () {
        console.log('sent_vanilla_rec_vanilla');
    });

    document.addEventListener('sent_jquery_rec_vanilla', function () {
        console.log('sent_jquery_rec_vanilla');
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(new Event("sent_vanilla_rec_vanilla"));
    document.dispatchEvent(new Event("sent_vanilla_rec_jquery"));

    $(document).trigger('sent_jquery_rec_jquery');
    $(document).trigger('sent_jquery_rec_vanilla');

}(jQuery));
```

Three events which are received and logged are:

- sent_vanilla_rec_vanilla
- sent_vanilla_rec_jquery
- sent_jquery_rec_jquery

When the event is sent via `$(document).trigger`, the event listener set up with `document.addEventListener` does not kick in. What's the reason for that, and how can I make it work?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you addEventListener after the triggers are registered?

Comment: May this be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18823872/jquery-dispatchevent-wrapper-method

Answer (score 9):

JQuery [apparently uses a custom event system](https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11047), so you can't listen to jQuery events with a regular event listener.  The aforementioned ticket mentions IE <9 as the culprit here, maybe jQuery 3 or 4 could make the switch.