# jQuery click event on link won't get catched in vaniila JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-3

I am using the following Vanilla binding in order to simulate the jQuery delegation event:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log("some element was clicked");
    console.log(e.target);

    //here's where I would filter by target
});
```

It is all working fine except when I try to trigger with jQuery a click event on a link element `<a href="#">`. Then it won't work at all. The vanilla click event handler won't be triggered.

[Reproduction working on `<b>` element](https://jsfiddle.net/s3q2q38z/4/)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('ul').append('<li><b>New</b></li>');
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log("some element was clicked");
    console.log(e.target);
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(){
    console.warn("-------Trigger--------")
 $('li').find('b').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div{
    background: yellow;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add element</button>
<span id="trigger">Trigger</span>
<div>
 Just focus the white panel and press any key. That will trigger the jQuery.click() event as you can see in the code.
</div>
<ul>
    <li>Old element</li>
    <li>Old element</li>
    <li><b>Old element</b></li>
</ul>
```

Instead, if I replace the link element for a bold one `<b>` it works as expected. 
What's going on?
[Reproduction not working on `<a>` element](https://jsfiddle.net/s3q2q38z/3/)

```js
$('button').click(function() {
    $('ul').append('<li><a href="#">New</a></li>');
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log("some element was clicked");
    console.log(e.target);
});

$(document).on('keydown', function(){
    console.warn("-------Trigger--------")
 $('li').find('a').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
div{
    background: yellow;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Add element</button>
<span id="trigger">Trigger</span>
<div>
 Just focus the white panel and press any key. That will trigger the jQuery.click() event as you can see in the code.
</div>
<ul>
    <li>Old element</li>
    <li>Old element</li>
    <li><a href="#">Old element</a></li>
</ul>
```

And no, I do not want to use `[0]` like this:

```
$('li').find('a')[0].click();
```

I want it to fire normally:

```
$('li').find('a').click();
```

Comment: I imagine this would also fail for `<form>`?

Comment: Are you saying that `$(document).on('keydown', function(){` does not trigger the click?

Comment: @Huangism nop, this is what is not being captured by vanilla `$('li').find('a').trigger('click');`. I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: @Alvaro yes that's what I am asking, you would have to bind the click with jquery for that to trigger it. Test here https://jsfiddle.net/s3q2q38z/5/

Comment: @Huangism can you then explain why it works properly when using the `b` element instead of the `a` one in `$('li').find('a').trigger('click');`

Comment: @Alvaro in detail no, but I would imagine it is because `b` is not a naturally clickable element

Comment: @Alvaro console.log a `<b>` element and a `<a>` element - they may return differently which is why you'd need (I say need, there might be other ways around it) the `[0]`

Comment: @Huangism trying to find an explanation to this, and hopefully, a solution.

Comment: I have seen other questions but none of them explains the behaviour, I think we need to dig into the library itself to figure out why. You could bind the click to the `li` and it would trigger the click for now. Until I have a better explanation for this, I deleted my answer for now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listen for jQuery Event With Vanilla JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915156/listen-for-jquery-event-with-vanilla-js). jQuery provides a layer of abstraction above native JS events, which means you cannot listen to jQuery events using vanilla JS.

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other question is reverse of this, like reverse flash

Comment: Is this what you're hoping for: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/s3q2q38z/6/)? (Admittedly using `each()` in this way is - basically - a little icky, but it does provide access to the `this` element-node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot trigger native click handlers in jQuery on links, it is disabled in the source and a comment says ["For cross-browser consistency, don't fire native .click() on links"](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L488).

So, you will either have to bind the document click handler using jQuery `$(document).on("click")` or call the nodes clickHandler directly `$('li').find('a')[0].click();`

Comment: Yep as expected the source simply don't allow it, probably for security reasons but I believe this is the right answer

Comment: You could also trigger click on the `li` and it would work as well

Comment: Interesting. I attached an onclick (i.e. the old way in plain JS) to the document and [it did fire](https://jsfiddle.net/s3q2q38z/7/).